# JSON многомерный массив экранизация цикла

Tags: php

Как вывести в цикле содержимое такого вида?

```
    $array = '{
        "Доступный цвет": [{
            "Красный": "red",
            "Белый": "white",
            "Синий": "blue",
            "Серый": "gray",
            "Черный": "black"
        }],
        "Доступный размер": [{
            "46 (S)": "46-s",
            "48 (M)": "48-m",
            "50 (L)": "50-l",
            "52 (XL)": "52-xl"
        }]
    }';
```

Пытаюсь вот так, не получается. Выводится ошибка, как исправить?

```
<?php
$array = json_decode($array);
foreach($array as $row => $key) {
echo $row;
foreach($key as $k => $t) {
echo $t;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

код под текущий json.

```
$array = json_decode($array, true);

foreach ($array['Доступный цвет'] as $list) {
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " - ". $value.'<br/>';
    }
}

foreach ($array['Доступный размер'] as $list) {
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " - ". $value.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

однако структура JSON "грязная", так не следует писать. Ключи не должны быть на русском языке. Пример "как надо":

```
{
  "colors": [
    {"key": "red", "label": "Красный"},
    {"key": "white", "label": "Белый"},
    {"key": "blue", "label": "Синий"},
    {"key": "gray", "label": "Серый"},
    {"key": "black", "label": "Черный"}
  ],
  "sizes": [
    {"key": "46-s", "label": "46 (S)"},
    {"key": "48-m", "label": "48 (M)"},
    {"key": "50-l", "label": "50 (L)"},
    {"key": "52-xl", "label": "52 (XL)"},
  ]
}
```